# How do I dynamically locate my project's output directory in a web application run with IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have an ASP.NET Web API project with a number of JSON files that I would like to reference in the code. I have them set to "copy-always" and they show up in the output directory on builds. The problem is I don't know how to actually reference the output directory.

I've seen a lot of answers to similar questions that say to use System.GetAssembly and use that to find the file path. However this does not work at all for web applications, because the GetAssembly or GetProcess methods just give me the IIS or IISExpress directory, not the project output folder.

How do I reference items in the project output folder without having the process running from that folder?

Edit: When I load the file by name, I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\myfile.json'.
```

Referencing by name looks in the IISExpress folder.

Relevant code snippet:

```
string file = "myjson.json";

var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
string JSON = myFile.ReadToEnd();
response.Content = new StringContent(JSON);
return response;
```

Comment: What happens when you reference them just by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any reason to put json file in your output directory then `use Content folder`, place your json file in content folder and refer it like this,

```
var File = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/myjson.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer any resource that is in your project's output directory by its name. For example a file with the name "File1.txt" can be accessed as follows:

```
var fileStream = File.Open("File1.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

In order to get absolute path in case of IIS, you can take the following approach:

```
var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");
```

Comment: File.Open still looks in the IISExpress directory. The second one takes me to Documents/My Web Sites/ which is full of empty folders. For contrast, my output directory is something like C:\MyApp\MyAppAPI\bin

Comment: You mentioned; "I have an ASP.NET Web API project..." I wonder why the second one pointed to "Documents/My Web Sites/". Are you sure you are working with Asp.NET WebAPI project?

Comment: The second approach would help you to point to your desired location if you modify it as follows: var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/FilesFolder"); Please remember when you will publish your API, the contents of bin were deployed in the folder that will be created for your API, and file will be located at the "/FilesFolder".